# Changing static navbar to static on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I made a simple website using bootstrap. It works fine on desktop but when i try it on mobile (ios) navbar navbar covers most of the screen.

So I used this but now it creates a void on top

```
< div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top; hidden-xs" role="navigation">
```

[image]

So the question is: 
How can i make it both desktop and mobile friendly. I tried looking for an answer for a while but couldnt find much to go on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is unclear. don't put a ; semicolon in your classes. Bootstrap's navbar collapses at the breakpoint you set in the customizer, it's usually 767px. This turns it into a toggle menu. Read the docs and look at the examples. Make changes to the larger viewport styles in the correct min-width. If you style a menu for larger screens outside a min-width media query it will not look correct on smaller viewports

Answer (score 1):

If you copied a Bootstrap example template they typically add padding to the body. Check all your containers from the navbar up with Developer tools to see what is causing the margin/padding.

Bootstrap is designed out of the box to just work, mobile responsive first and up. You shouldn't need to adjust much to do what you need unless you've gone ahead and customized the CSS on your own.